# Timeline of Sports Moderators

Tags: discussion, moderators

As this site's moderators have changed over the years, here's a place to keep track of those changes for those curious.

Answer (score 6):

Most of this comes from the [Moderators Pro Tempore](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/120/revisions) question edit history, for those curious.

- February 2012: Site opens in public beta.
- March 2012: [Michael Myers](http://sports.stackexchange.com/users/12), [Tonny Madsen](http://sports.stackexchange.com/users/38), and [Jamauss](http://sports.stackexchange.com/users/18) are appointed first moderators
- August 2012: Tonny Madsen stepped down, and [edmastermind29](http://sports.stackexchange.com/users/527) filled in.
- June 2017: edmastermind29 stepped down, and [Philip Kendall](https://sports.stackexchange.com/users/6126) stepped in
- June 2020: First [public elections](https://sports.stackexchange.com/election/1) held; [Philip Kendall](https://sports.stackexchange.com/users/6126), [Joe Matise](https://sports.stackexchange.com/users/6232/joe), and [Nij](https://sports.stackexchange.com/users/9319/nij) elected.